# Tornado application asynchronous mode

Tags: python, web-applications, asynchronous, tornado, wsgi

I just wonder if there is the method to verify that a tornado application which is really running in asynchronous mode under Tornado wSGI.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tornado WSGI, I can guarantee that Tornado is **not** running asynchronously. The [documentation for tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication) states this:

> A WSGI equivalent of tornado.web.Application.
>
> WSGIApplication is very similar to tornado.web.Application, **except no
>   asynchronous methods are supported (since WSGI does not support
>   non-blocking requests properly)**. If you call self.flush() or other
>   asynchronous methods in your request handlers running in a
>   WSGIApplication, we throw an exception.

Comment: Thx a lot @dano, so in order to benefit the asynchronous, the Tornado needs to be run as a server instead of WSGI container?

Comment: @perigee Yep! If you want to run a more production-ready server in front of it, The recommended choice is Nginx: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/overview.html#running-tornado-in-production